# UITableView reloadData() causing reload to UISearchBar inside every sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbardelegate

I have a tableview which has 2 sections. Both of the sections have `UISearchBar` in the `indexPath.row` 0 and the rest of the rows in each section populate the list of array.
Whenever I type some text in search bar every time the `searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)` delegate method gets called and inside the delegate method I call `tableView.reloadData()` to reload the search results in `tableview`.

[image: tableview]

Now the problem is each time the tableView reloads the UISearchBar reloads too (as UISearchbar is in row number 1) and every time the SearchBar keypad Resigns.

Instead of doing `tableView.reloadData()` I even tried to reload every row except the first one using bellow code

```
let allButFirst = (self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows ?? []).filter { $0.section != selectedSection || $0.row != 0 }
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: allButFirst, with: .automatic)
```

But no luck. App gets crashed saying

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to insert row 2 into section 0, but there are only 2 rows in section 0 after the update'

Comment: Do you use reusable cell? How do you create cells in `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)`?

Comment: yes 
let cell = tbl_Filter.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SearchRangeCell")!

                cell.selectionStyle = .none

                let searchBar = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as? UISearchBar

Comment: Yes its in tableView

Comment: Just reloading rows cannot cause an `NSInternalInconsistencyException`. And why don't you display the search bar(s) in a section **header**?

Comment: the crash happens because when i try to reload rows at indexpathset (not table) after a net sets of seach results comes.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably changing the data source and then you are reloading rows at index paths what doesn't exist yet.

It is not so easy, but let's have an example: Before you start typing, the search result will contain something like this:

`["aa", "ab", "ba", "bb"]`

Then you will type `"a"` to the search bar and data source changes into: 
`["aa", "ab"]`

```
tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row:3, section: 0), IndexPath(row:4, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
```

then you delete everything in this searchbar and your data source will change to the default: `["aa", "ab", "ba", "bb"]`

so in this case you need to call:

```
tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:3, section: 0), IndexPath(row:4, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
```

I created some working example - without storyboard source, I believe it is pretty simple to recreated it according this class.

```
class SearchCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField:UITextField?
}

class TextCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var label:UILabel?
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView?
    weak var firstSectionTextField: UITextField?
    var originalDataSource:[[String]] = [["aa","ab","ba","bb"], ["aa","ab","ba","bb"]]
    var dataSource:[[String]] = []
    let skipRowWithSearchInput = 1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        dataSource = originalDataSource
        tableView?.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView?.tableHeaderView = UIView()
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return dataSource.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return dataSource[section].count + skipRowWithSearchInput
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0, let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "search", for: indexPath) as? SearchCell {
            cell.textField?.removeTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChangeText(sender:)), for: .editingChanged)
            cell.textField?.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChangeText(sender:)), for: .editingChanged)
            if indexPath.section == 0 {
                firstSectionTextField = cell.textField
            }
            return cell
        } else if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "text", for: indexPath) as? TextCell  {
            cell.label?.text = dataSource[indexPath.section][indexPath.row - skipRowWithSearchInput]
            return cell
        } else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }

    @objc func textFieldDidChangeText(sender: UITextField) {

        let section = sender == firstSectionTextField ? 0 : 1
        let text = sender.text ?? ""
        let oldDataSource:[String] = dataSource[section]
        //if the search bar is empty then use the original data source to display all results, or initial one
        let newDataSource:[String] = text.count == 0 ? originalDataSource[section] : originalDataSource[section].filter({$0.contains(text)})
        var insertedRows:[IndexPath] = []
        var deletedRows:[IndexPath] = []
        var movedRows:[(from:IndexPath,to:IndexPath)] = []

        //resolve inserted rows
        newDataSource.enumerated().forEach { (tuple) in let (toIndex, element) = tuple
            if oldDataSource.contains(element) == false {
                insertedRows.append(IndexPath(row: toIndex + skipRowWithSearchInput, section: section))                    
            }
        }

        //resolve deleted rows
        oldDataSource.enumerated().forEach { (tuple) in let (fromIndex, element) = tuple
            if newDataSource.contains(element) == false {
                deletedRows.append(IndexPath(row: fromIndex + skipRowWithSearchInput, section: section))
            }
        }

        //resolve moved rows
        oldDataSource.enumerated().forEach { (tuple) in let (index, element) = tuple
            if newDataSource.count > index, let offset = newDataSource.firstIndex(where: {element == $0}), index != offset {
                movedRows.append((from: IndexPath(row: index + skipRowWithSearchInput, section: section), to: IndexPath(row: offset + skipRowWithSearchInput, section: section)))
            }
        }

        //now set dataSource for uitableview, right before you are doing the changes
        dataSource[section] = newDataSource
        tableView?.beginUpdates()
        if insertedRows.count > 0 {
            tableView?.insertRows(at: insertedRows, with: .automatic)
        }
        if deletedRows.count > 0 {
            tableView?.deleteRows(at: deletedRows, with: .automatic)
        }
        movedRows.forEach({
            tableView?.moveRow(at: $0.from, to: $0.to)
        })

        tableView?.endUpdates()
    }
}
```

the result:

[image: Reloading Specific row in table View]

If do you need to clarify something, feel free to ask in comment.

Comment: Thanks Lukas, I will try those ways.

Comment: @SnigdharaniSahu since you add the picture of your case, I am afraid, that the easier options what I suggested will not help you. You are using the headers for sections already, right? So if you are interested I can provide you (as an update of my answer) more complex example about handling dataSource change.

Comment: Please can you tell me the best way ?

Comment: Main problem is when i reload my table or section , the search bar get reloaded too. And the searchbar keypad resigns. How can i Prevent that ?

Comment: @SnigdharaniSahu I updated the answer, hope it will help you, or somebody.

Comment: Lukas , Thnx, i tried with your second option and it worked only i took two sections one for search field and another for reloading data.
I took separate custom cell for search and took outlet in that class itself.
and in viewForHeaderInSection i returned customCell.contentView
Then I called tableview ReloadData in searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
It worked without problm.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
//Do the update thing
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked.
I took two sections one for search field and another for reloading data (rows populating data).
I took separate custom cell for search and took outlet in that class itself.
and in viewForHeaderInSection I used tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier:) and  returned customCell.contentView
Then I called tableview.ReloadData() in searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String)
It worked without problem.